# In Visual Studio 2008 using VB.NET, why are my calls to my shared library only returning correct results when I actually step into the code?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, dependency-injection, webforms, unity-container

I've written a couple of shared libraries in C# using the 3.5 SP1 .NET Framework, one for data access and one for business logic.

These libraries are being consumed by a Webform application written in VB.NET, which is also running on the 3.5 SP1 .NET Framework. The Webform application is a legacy application, that I'm trying to add some new functionality to. One thing I did to the legacy application was to add the Unity Application Block, so that I could do dependency injection. That seems to be working fine.

The problem I'm experiencing is that when I make calls to methods on the resolved objects, I only get the correct results when I step thru the code or when the method doesn't take any parameters.

Take the following code...

```
Public Sub GetPartners()
    Dim container As IUnityContainer = HttpContext.Current.Application("GlobalUnityContainerKey")
    Dim partnerFactory As IUpsellPartnerFactory = container.Resolve(Of IUpsellPartnerFactory)()
    Dim criteria As IUpsellCriteria = New UpsellCriteria(DateTime.Now)
    Dim partners As List(Of IUpsellPartner) = partnerFactory.RetrieveByCriteria(criteria)

    If partners.Count > 0 Then

        'Add each Partner to a dropdown list.

    End If

End Sub
```

If I attach the debugger and just let this code run, it'll return an empty list of partners. However, if I put a breakpoint at the very first line, and then step thru the code until at least the line where I declare the IUpsellCriteria object, I'll get a list of 5 partners. That's the correct result.

I used to not declare a variable for the criteria object. Instead, I'd construct a new UpsellCriteria and pass it directly into the RetrieveByCriteria call. When, I did that I had to actually step into the RetrieveByCriteria call, before I'd get the correct results. But, changing the code to be the way I'm showing it now fixed that.

Does anybody have any idea what's going on here? Why do I have to step thru the code to get it to run correctly?

Comment: what is the nature of `GetPartners` is it in a module or class?  can you show how you invoke it?

Comment: GetPartners is contained in the code-behind class for the webform. It is called from another method in the class during page load.

Answer (score 0):

So, it turned out to be nothing to do with where I was looking. Instead, it was a timing issue between the web server and the database server. The IUpsellCriteria contains a sale date field which is used to filter which options are available for a sale. The database uses a stored procedure to actually retrieve the results, and if there is no end date then it was using the current datetime. However, there was just enough of a difference in time between the web server and database server, that the stored procedure wouldn't return any results. So, I changed the way I handle options without end dates, and the problem is solved.